# Escape single quote and wildcard in TSQL LIKE

Tags: sql-server, escaping, sql-like

We are making an update to the way we structure the `ProjectID` field in our database. Currently there are values such as `PD80400` which identifies a specific project.

There are likely stored procedures which use the `PDXXXXX` format in the `Where` clause such as `ProjectID NOT LIKE 'PD%'`

> I need to search our database for any Procedures / Views / Tables / Function / etc. which contains a reference to `PD%`
>   Currently I am using the following script but am having trouble capturing my test procedure which contains `Where ProjectID NOT LIKE 'PD%'` without searching for `%PD%`.... whcih is returning far too many undesired results such as anything with the words `Update, Updated, etc`.

My script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[name], b.[text], CASE WHEN a.type IN ('FN', 'TF') THEN 'Function' WHEN a.type = 'P' THEN 'Stored Procedure' WHEN a.type = 'V' THEN 'View'  ELSE 'Unknown' END AS 'ObjectType', a.type
FROM sysobjects a
INNER JOIN syscomments b on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.[text] LIKE '%PD%' AND a.name = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA_TBG_MM_TestProcedure_PDSearch'--AND b.[text] NOT LIKE 'update%' AND b.[text] NOT LIKE 'EmpD%' AND b.[text] NOT LIKE 'updated' AND a.name NOT LIKE 'Z_OLD%' AND a.name NOT LIKE 'ZOLD%'
ORDER BY ObjectType
```

> How should I format my `LIKE` statement in order to capture examples like I listed above without all the extra results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the `%` wildcard by specifying an `escape` character, and to include a single quote use two single quotes like so:

```
select 
    a.[name]
  , b.[text]
  , case when a.type in ('fn', 'tf') then 'Function' 
         when a.type = 'P' then 'Stored Procedure' 
         when a.type = 'V' then 'View'  
         else 'Unknown' end as 'ObjectType', a.type
from sysobjects a
  inner join syscomments b on a.id = b.id
where b.[text] like '%''PD\%%' escape '\'
order by ObjectType
```

---

To test with two dummy procedures:

```
create procedure dbo.pd_search as 
select * from master..spt_values 
where number = 1
  and name not like 'PD%'
go
create procedure dbo.pd_search_other as 
select * from master..spt_values 
where number = 1
  and name <> 'PD'
go
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KPC17170

returns:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------+------+
|   name    |                text                |    ObjectType    | type |
+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------+------+
| pd_search | create procedure dbo.pd_search as  | Stored Procedure | P    |
|           | select * from master..spt_values   |                  |      |
|           | where number = 1                   |                  |      |
|           |   and name not like 'PD%'          |                  |      |
+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------+------+
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, that worked better than I hoped for